# 'int' object is not subscriptable error in python program using sqlite3 database while trying to insert database row values in entry box

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Im Facing an error while trying to insert database row values in entry box, but an error is occuring which is given below:

```
def search_db(self,*args,**kwargs):
        with sqlite3.connect('restaurent_pos.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()

            c.execute("SELECT * FROM Kitchen_store WHERE Item_name = ?",(self.cb_1.get(),))
            rows = c.fetchone()
            #result= c.execute(self.cb_1.get(), )
            print(rows)
            for r in rows:
                self.n1 = r[5]
                self.n2 = r[6]
                self.n3 = r[7]
            db.commit()

            self.qty_entry.delete(0,END)
            self.qty_entry.insert(0, self.n1)
            self.rate_entry.delete(0,END)
            self.rate_entry.insert(0, self.n2)
            self.chef_entry.delete(0,END)
            self.chef_entry.insert(0, self.n3)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mntech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\my data\resto.py", line 2002, in search_db
    self.n1 = r[5]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You have **one row**: `rows = c.fetchone()`. So `for r in rows:` gives you a single column. Remove your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's should work:

```
print(rows)
self.n1 = rows[5]
self.n2 = rows[6]
self.n3 = rows[7]
```

Comment: the call to `db.commit()` is useless (the OP is just querying data). And since `fetchone()` returns a single row, the variable would be better named `row` (singular) ;-)